# Simple Groovy Matcher

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to understand why this always returns, "It will be stopped":

```
def test = "started"

if (test  ==~ "deallocated"||"stopped") {
println "it will be stopped"
}
```

I'm new to groovy and still learning and I can't understand why this if condition doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the OR in the matcher should look like:

```
def test = "stopped"

if (test  ==~ "deallocated|stopped") {
    println "it will be stopped"
}
```